# getURI showing JSP name not browser URL?

Tags: jsp, analytics

I am trying to pull in the URL as viewed in the browser address bar into a Google Analytics tag.  I used the 
 
                <%
                  String getURI=request.getRequestURI();
                %>

method but it's showing me the JSP file name/path rather than what is in the browser.

Am I doing this wrong or is that what is expected since I am doing this in a developer ToolKit on a VM? I have looked through the forums and looked on Google, but can't find an answer to my question, nothing seems to address the possibility of it working differently in a local environment, so I think I have done something wrong.

Comment: It depends on servlet container/application server. Which one do you use?

Comment: No, it does absolutely not depend on servlet container. The behavior is the same on all containers conforming the servlet spec.

Answer (score 2):

If a JSP is been [forwarded](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) by a front controller, then the [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) will indeed return the URI of the JSP instead of the original URI as the client initially requested (as visible in the browser's address bar).

In case of a forward, the original request URI is available as a request attribute with a key as identified by [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI), which is [`javax.servlet.forward.request_uri`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI).

So, this should do:

```
String getURI = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```

Or when you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older (this constant was introduced in Servlet 3.0):

```
String getURI = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```

By the way, it's in JSP EL available as follows:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is what it is supposed to do. Use request.getRequestUrl(), this will give you complete (http://www...../xyz.jsp)

Edit 
Refer here for description on two method 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Edit 2 
so in short your query is that you need the filename of tge file you are in at.

Try something like

```
request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/"))
```

This will give you string welcome.html.if you are inside welcome.html
you can prepend a '/'. 
Not sure if there is a direct method to what you seek

Comment: Try getContextPath(), this will give you the context of the request.

Comment: Context path? Are you stabbing in the dark or so? Run/experiment it yourself locally first, please.

Comment: Yea sorry got confused. He is asking for the latter part while getContextPath() would give the part before it.

Comment: Something like , This should work for you. request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/"))

Comment: Edited the post with the answer

Comment: Check that out and let us know if it works or resolve your issue

Comment: It pulled up the end of the string (/filename.jsp) but unfortunately, not the HTML page.  My client just told me they want to do something else now so I guess this was all for nothing. :|

Comment: What do u mean it pulled out jsp and not html ? Also clients will be clients always changing requirements. And dont worry brother nothing is for nothing. We have learnt something new today. By the way. If the answer answered the question please mark it as accepted as it would be helpful for other people landing here. Regards

Comment: @Mukul, the results I saw were: /filename.jsp instead of /product-category_color_blah_blah and everything after the / in the browser window. But you're right, nothing is for nothing.